# Seleccionar un valor de un Array

Tags: java, array

Estoy intentando pedir por consola un número del 1 al 12 y que al digitar el número muestre el mes correspondiente a ese número.

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cal;

    System.out.print("Digite el mes: ");
    cal = entrada.nextInt();

    String[] meses = {"Enero", "febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio"+
            "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};
```

> Como hacer para que al digital el numero 3 escoja del Array la palabra marzo y lo imprima en pantalla?.

Comment: Intentaste imprimir meses[2]? (los arrays parten con índice 0)

Comment: Fíjate además que junio y julio, saldrían juntos al apretar un 6, ya que pusiste un +, en lugar de una coma

Comment: Tienes un error al definir el array, debe ser sin el signo "+" después de "Junio", esto sería; String[] meses = {"Enero", "febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio",
            "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"}; ,incluso te sugiero validar solo valores dentro del rango.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes de usar el numero que has seleccionado y restarle una unidad, ya que los `Arrays` comienzan en el índice `0`, entonces tu código quedaría más o menos:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cal;

    System.out.print("Digite el mes: ");
    cal = entrada.nextInt();

    String[] meses = {"Enero", "febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio"
        , "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};

    System.out.print("El mes seleccionado fue " + meses[cal-1] ); //restando una unidad
```

De este modo, si es que escribes 2, el índice apuntaría a marzo, restando una unidad, esto apuntaría a febrero que es la opción correcta.

*Además debes de fijarte que si seleccionas el mes 6, te saldrá **juniojulio** juntos, ya que con el símbolo `+`, estarás concadenando ambos meses, debería ser una coma, como lo he puesto en el código anterior.*

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me gusta la imagen que muestra el resultado. <3 <3

Comment: ScreenToGif, bastante útil :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente obtén el valor dentro del array de esta forma:

```
System.out.println(meses[cal-1]);
```

Incluso **te sugiero validar para únicamente obtener valores dentro del rango de la longitud del array**:

```
 //Validación
 if((cal-1)>= meses.length || cal <= 0){
      System.out.println("Debe ingresar un numero valido del 1 al " + (meses.length));      
 }else{
      //Imprime valor
      System.out.println(meses[cal-1]);    
 }
```

Código incluyendo validación:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cal;

    System.out.print("Digite el mes: ");
    cal = entrada.nextInt();

    String[] meses = {"Enero", "febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio",
            "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};


     //Validación
     if((cal-1)>= meses.length || cal <= 0){
          System.out.println("Debe ingresar un numero valido del 1 al " + (meses.length));      
     }else{
         //Imprime valor, si el elemento ingresado esta dentro del rango de valores del array
          System.out.println(meses[cal-1]);    
     } 

   }
```

---

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]